# XCode Editor Bug? Insertion point and lines change

Tags: xcode

I've posted a video of this happening to YouTube, this was the easiest way to show what is actually happening. That video is at: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XwXbilxME1A

Around 6 seconds in I was just typing, no key commands or anything. All of a sudden some lines disappear, some appear, and the insertion point changes. This is only a visual issue, if I keep typing it will fix it self. Even so, it is very distracting. I also seem to recall it happening before and once I changed my insertion point or something the changes were no longer visual only

Comment: Did you apply all software updates? You could have a hardware problem, like bad memory.

Comment: Sorry I meant to include that I have the most recent non-beta version of XCode running, Version 3.2.4 (Xcode IDE: 1708.0; Xcode Core: 1705.0). I just upgraded to a new system, and this happened on my last as well so it's not a hardware problem...